# Using returns from two different methods in subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, invoke, superclass

I'm struggling with one of the final parts of a school assignment.

I had asked this question on another question I had but did not receive an answer.
I have two methods in my super class that I need to use in my sub class and the one method must be invoked inside of the other to return a result, I'm stumped on how to do this.

```
public class Pay
{
private float hours;
private float rate;
private int hrsStr;
float gross;
double tax; 

public void calc_Payroll()
{
    if (hrsStr != 0)
        gross = hrsStr + ((hours - hrsStr) * 1.33f) * rate;
    else
        gross = hours * rate;
}

public void tax(double a)
    {
    if (gross <= 399.99)
                tax = .92;
                else
                    if (gross <= 899.99)
                        tax = .88;
                    else 
                        tax = .84;
    }


    public void setHours(float a)
    {
        hours = a;
    }

    public float getHours()
    {
        return hours;
    }

    public void setRate(float a)
    {
        rate = a;
    }

    public float getRate()
    {
        return rate;
    }

    public void setHrsStr(int a)
    {
        hrsStr = a;
    }

    public int getHrsStr()
    {
        return hrsStr;
    }
}
```

That is the entire superclass and i need to call the calc_Payroll() method and the tax() method to the subclass, well I need tax() to be inside calc_Payroll() because I need to calculate the net pay from those two methods.

```
public class Payroll extends Pay
{
float net;
@Override
public void calc_Payroll()
    {
                 //I need to calculate the the net pay here. 
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the same logic. No ?

Comment: Provide more details of what "calculate net pay" needs to do. What, ideally, do you need to call inside of your override of `calc_Payroll()`?

Comment: Calculate net pay just needs to return the result of gross * tax = net.  I would like to keep it as simple as possible ideally only calling the result of the super calc_Payroll() and Tax(double a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you struggling with the syntax of Java?

```
public class Payroll extends Pay
{
    float net;

    @Override
    public void calc_Payroll()
    {
        // you can call `super.calc_Payroll()`
        // you can call `tax(double a)`
    }
}
```

Comment: In certain aspects of it I am yes.  I will try this.

Comment: I tried this and received errors on the tax line                                                        - Syntax error on token "double", delete this 
  token
- Line breakpoint:Payroll [line: 12] - 
  calc_Payroll()
- a cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: That's your issue -- I was giving you the syntax. Clearly you'd need to have an `a` variable initialized, and be doing things in the correct order.

Comment: Right -- you can call that function, but your actual code would be `tax(a);`

Comment: okay so that got rid of the syntax error but it still says a cannot be resolved to a variable, I could call the variables but I thought that happened already when using 'extends'?

Comment: What shall tax(...) be called on? This could be tax(30.5)  ... if you call tax(b) you must define b in the calling method before. If it's tax(a) than `a`  is a different `a`  in the calling method than the ´a´ in the called method though the value is given from here to there.

Comment: tax is going to assigned a variable depending on the gross

Comment: This may help you understand variable scope: http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html